# "Join" multiple Algolia indices?

Tags: algolia

Is it possible to "join" indices in [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com) to get a merged result?

For example:

If I have two indices : one for 'users', and one for 'events'. Users each have `id` and `name` attributes. Events each have `date` and `userId` attributes.

How would I go about searching for all users named "bob", and for each user also return the next 5 events associated with them?

Is it possible to "join" them like you would in a relational database? Or do I need to search for users, then iterate through the hits, searching for events for each user? What's the best solution for this type of query here?

Answer (score 3):

Algolia is not designed as a relational database. To get to what you're trying to achieve, you have to transform all your records into "flat" objects (meaning, each object also includes all their linked dependencies).

In your case, what I would do is to add a new key to your user records, named `events` and have it be an array of events (just like you save them in the `events` table). This way, you got all the information needed in one call.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks. Yeah - trouble with that approach is that I just want the next few events chronologically. Is it possible to filter an attribute of a record? In this case, if all user events (past and future) are in an attribute on the user, I'd need to filter those events to list only the next 5 starting on today's date. Would also make for a huge index as users could have hundreds of events.

Comment: Or should I set up a cron process to remove any past events from every user in the index periodically? What's the right way to do this?

Comment: The way I would do it is to "invert" the data. Meaning that instead of having a list of all users, with an `events` subkey, you actually have a list of events, and add a `users` subkey to each of them (which would be an array of objects representing the users). That way you can filter on `users.id == 42 AND event.date > {yourdate}` to get all events of a specific user relative to a specific date.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that's a good way of getting events for a user. But in my case I need to search users, getting 50 per page, and display the next 5 events for each of those users. If I search the user index, then the events index for each returned user to get the events. Seems like a case for denormalization. I'm not sure is the best way of doing that.

Comment: In that case I would suggest keeping the first version (storing users, each with a list of events). In the front-end you would display only the 5 first events (even if the list contains more). I would also recommend regularly purging the index of outdated events (maybe through a CRON job)